# Regex on a string that may or may not be comma separated

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture a line of string that may or may not have a comma (:only 0 or 1 comma will be given). So the data will be something like below and regex execution will happen line by line.

```
cake,strawberry
shortbread
english-muffin,blueberry
```

Desired capture of first group:

```
cake
shortbread
english-muffin
```

Desired capture of last group:

```
strawberry

blueberry
```

What I initially tried was `(.*?)(,)?(.*)` but that captured `cake,strawberry` as one group. I also tried several others but it was more or less the same. Should I take this as 2 separate patterns?

Comment: Although you specified regex as your method, have you thought about simply splitting lines at the first instance of a comma, should one exist? That would be a lot more efficient and straight forward.

Comment: what if you have a line with words that are space-delimited? The reason I am asking is because, in my opinion, accepting a line that doesn't have a comma seems dangerous to me.

Comment: @CJK I was trying to make a VIEW from joining tables, so the execution is done in SQL :)

Comment: @hfontanez Thanks for the opinion. But can you please elaborate on why it is dangerous a little bit? From my side, it was just a task requirement that I need to fulfill

Comment: @PuffedRiceCrackers because it could mean that words are delimited by something other than a comma. In which case, you could interpret that as an error, or that you need to account for other delimiting characters. Since I don't know the system, it is just speculation. But those are the kind of edge cases you need to explore and figure out who to address.

Comment: @hfontanez Oh, did you mean cases like when the input was
`apple pie\ncake,cherry` and the first group is `apple pie\ncake` rather than `apple pie`? Luckily, in my case regex is executed on a single line and the data is predefined so not as arbitrary as when we are working on a user data. Thanks for the advice, let me know and if you meant a different case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `([^,]*)(?:,(.*))?`:

- `([^,]*)` match zero or more "not a comma" and capture it
- `(?:,(.*))?` optionally, match a comma and capture everything after it

Note: `(?:)` is a non-capturing group.

Python demo:

```py
import re

lines = ['cake,strawberry',
         'shortbread',
         'english-muffin,blueberry']

for line in lines:
    print(re.match('([^,]*)(?:,(.*))?',line).groups())
```

```
('cake', 'strawberry')
('shortbread', None)
('english-muffin', 'blueberry')
```